# How to print Leopard 10.5.8 (w/Epson on Netgear WGPS606)

Tags: mac-osx, wifi, osx-leopard, print-server, netgear

I am trying to access my Epson Stylus Photo R1900 which is connected to my Netgear WGPS606.  I am currently running OSX 10.5.8.  I was able to print directly from my machine without any problems and I was able to print over the network with my Windows machines too.  My only problem is this MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the obvious question is, do you have the proper printer driver for Leo?

Please download and install the printer driver from this page.

[Epson Support Leopard](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/SupportLeopard.jsp)

If that doesn't work, can you expand, "I was able to print directly from my machine without any problems"?

Do you have other Mac computers with Leopard installed that can print to the R1900? If you do, have you isolated your MBP is the only machine that can not print to the R1900? Can your MBP print and transfer files to other printer/machines in the LAN?

Lastly, is the router preventing your MBP from printer?

Comment: Yes, I have the correct Leopard driver.  When I said I could print "directly", I meant I could connect the R1900 via USB to my MBP (which proves the drivers are correct).  My problem is printing over the network from the MBP.  I can print over the network from all my PCs with no problem.